# Links work in broswer and provide JSON but not with Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, service, controllers

I'm trying to use Angular to get two responses.

One, a response if the website uses green energy

Two, what are alternatives to this website.

```
app.controller('QueryController',['$http',function($http){
var site = this
site.green = []
site.alternatives = []

$http.get('http://api.thegreenwebfoundation.org/greencheck/' + 'www.apple.com').success(function(data){ 
  console.log(data.result);
});

$http.get('http://www.similarsitesearch.com/api/similar/' + 'www.apple.com').success(function(data){ 
  console.log("it worked");
}); }]);
```

As you can see both of these links provided JSON. But when I try to run this I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.similarsitesearch.com/api/similar/www.apple.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'd love any advice on the correct way to do this, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a cross domain issue. Your browser will prevent ajax requests to other domains for security reasons.

You can research if these sites support CORS or can be fetched using JSONP. There are however some security concerns with JSONP especially if you are dealing with third parties.

Another alternative is to setup a reverse proxy on your own domain that makes the cross domain request.

Comment: +1 - Almost certainly cross-domain issue. I was curious for my own education, so created the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joellee/ozze0twg/ which attempts open both urls with jQuery. The first one succeeds, but the second one fails, even though both can be opened successfully if entered in browser address line.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what the next steps are to make this work.